# Permission table in database phpmyadmin

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I had a 4 users ... and all have different permissions...so how can I assign permission to them in database ....

I made 3 tables in database ->

1)user table
2)permission_type table
3)permission table

help me out ....thanks in advance

Comment: Can you send me what your database looks like?

Comment: Could you add some extra information to your question? What sort of query are you trying to execute? What have you tried to run? What errors are you getting with it?

Comment: i want to make a permission table ..... we have 3 users ...admin,developer and client .... admin have all privillage , client only see described feature and as so developer .... i not going to deside how to make database for that ...can u help me out

Answer (score 0):

You need a table to store the relation between permission and user.

user_has_permission

- user_id
- permission_id

But besides that I can't really say anything - After all you haven't really provided us enough information.